# How do you send an email using a template with AWS SES Java SDK sesv2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send an email using a template with the AWS Java SDK v2 2.17.235. I have created the template and read at least 2 dozen pages of documentation at this point. 6 hours in I have not been able to find a single example or a shred of anything helpful in regards to this check the documentation several times read every article.

I can send other emails just fine but I want to use templating moving forward. Again, I've created the template, I can get the template, etc. None of that is helpful, I need to use a template that I've created to send an email. Here's what my code looks like

```
        try (
            SesV2Client client = SesV2Client.builder()
                    .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                    .build()) {
        

        Template template = Template.builder().templateName("SiteUpdateTemplate").templateData(TEMPLATE_DATA).build();

        EmailContent emailContent = EmailContent.builder().template(Template.builder().templateName("SiteUpdateTemplate").templateData(TEMPLATE_DATA).build()).build();
        GetEmailTemplateRequest getEmailTemplateRequest = GetEmailTemplateRequest.builder().templateName("SiteUpdateTemplate").build();
        GetEmailTemplateResponse getEmailTemplateResponse = client.getEmailTemplate(getEmailTemplateRequest);


        SendEmailRequest request = SendEmailRequest.builder()
                .configurationSetName(CONFIGSET)
                .fromEmailAddress(FROM)
                .listManagementOptions(ListManagementOptions.builder().contactListName(CONTACT_LIST).topicName(TOPIC_SITE_UPDATES).build())
                .fromEmailAddressIdentityArn(IDENTITYARN)
                .feedbackForwardingEmailAddress(FROM)
                .feedbackForwardingEmailAddressIdentityArn(IDENTITYARN)
                .destination(Destination.builder().toAddresses("test@gmail.com").build())
//

                .content(emailContent)
```

Is anyone able to give me an example or point to somewhere that has the information I need?

**EDIT**

To me it seems like the only way this would work is if I could somehow get the ARN of the template only theres no way to get the ARN of the template that I'm aware of.
[image]

**EDIT 2**

I need to be more specific so I'm adding some additional details. I think that I may have jumped ahead to an incorrect conclusion based on what I was seeing. When I send the email using the template I

- Do no get any errors (From my end it appears to send... I guess?)
- The "Emails Sent" goes up by the amount I sent in the AWS Console. So by that metric I guess it did technically send or at least it tried to?
- I have bounce/complaints setup with the SQS/SNS stack that remains empty after the email has been sent.

I honestly don't even know what to do at this point. No failures, the emails are never received and my sent emails go up by the amount I send in the AWS console. I have not received a single one of these 57 emails [image]

Comment: The thing is I don't even know that for sure. I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible at this point. This should never, ever be the case.

Comment: Yes -- sending an email using a template with the SesV2Client is possible.. Here is more infor about templates in the Service DEV Guide. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-personalized-email-manage-templates.html, I will add a new issue in Github so this example is created.

Comment: @smac2020 thanks for the link much appreciated but i've read over, and over that. Doesn't have anything to do with sending an email with SesV2Client.

Comment: See answer that shows this logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution. First create a template by following this topic in the SES DEV Guide:

[Create an email template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-personalized-email-api.html)

I followed that and created a template as shown here:

[image]

Here is your Java V2 code that uses this template to send an email. Notice that you only have to reference the template name when you create a **Template** object.

**UPDATE**

WHen sending an email with a template - you must specify all variables you use in the template. The example template you create in the SES DEV Guide uses 2 variables:

```
{
  "Template": {
    "TemplateName": "MyTemplate",
    "SubjectPart": "Greetings, {{name}}!",
    "HtmlPart": "<h1>Hello {{name}},</h1><p>Your favorite animal is {{favoriteanimal}}.</p>",
    "TextPart": "Dear {{name}},\r\nYour favorite animal is {{favoriteanimal}}."
  }
}
```

This means you need to specify both **name** and **favoriteanimal** in your code when defining the **Template** object. If you DO NOT specify all variables in the template - SES does not send the email, as discussed here.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-resolve-emails-not-delivered/

**Java Code:**

```
package com.example.sesv2;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.Destination;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.EmailContent;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.SendEmailRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.SesV2Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.SesV2Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sesv2.model.Template;


/**
 * Before running this AWS SDK for Java (v2) example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class SendEmailTemplate {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                final String usage = "\n" +
                        "Usage:\n" +
                        "    <sender> <recipient> <subject> \n\n" +
                        "Where:\n" +
                        "    template - the name of the email template" +
                        "    sender - An email address that represents the sender. \n"+
                        "    recipient - An email address that represents the recipient. \n" ;

                if (args.length != 3) {
                        System.out.println(usage);
                        System.exit(1);
                }

                String templateName = "MyTemplate";
                String sender = "<Enter sender>" ; //args[0];
                String recipient =  "<Enter recipient>" ; // ; args[1];
                Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
                SesV2Client sesv2Client = SesV2Client.builder()
                        .region(region)
                        .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                        .build();

                send(sesv2Client, sender, recipient, templateName);
        }

        // snippet-start:[ses.java2.sendmessage.sesv2.main]
        public static void send(SesV2Client client,
                                String sender,
                                String recipient,
                                String templateName

        ){

                Destination destination = Destination.builder()
                        .toAddresses(recipient)
                        .build();

                 Template myTemplate = Template.builder()
                    .templateName(templateName)
                    .templateData("{\n" +
                            "  \"name\": \"Jason\"\n," +
                            "  \"favoriteanimal\": \"Cat\"\n" +
                            "}")
                    .build();

                EmailContent emailContent = EmailContent.builder()
                        .template(myTemplate)
                         .build();

                SendEmailRequest emailRequest = SendEmailRequest.builder()
                        .destination(destination)
                          .content(emailContent)
                        .fromEmailAddress(sender)
                        .build();

                try {
                        System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through Amazon SES " + "using the AWS SDK for Java...");
                        client.sendEmail(emailRequest);
                        System.out.println("email based on a template was sent");

                } catch (SesV2Exception e) {
                        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
                        System.exit(1);
                }
        }
    }
```

After i ran this code -- I got my email based on the template:

[image]

Comment: If you look at my code that I posted I'm doing the exact same thing. I need to update my post I think to be a little more specific. I don't get any errors the email send, its never bounces and I can also see my sent emails count go up in the AWS SES console. Maybe my problem isn't that they're not sending but instead that they are never being received. I have bounces and complaints also set up and that inbox is empty.

Comment: See my update for more information and see the successful email based on a template.

Comment: This Java example is now part of the AWS Java Dev Guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/java_ses_code_examples.html#w118aac15c14b9c61c13